# Optimization relationships beetween entityes

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data

I have entity like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "test")
public class TestEntity {

@ElementCollection
@Column(name = "record_type_id", nullable = false)
@CollectionTable(name = "test_entity_record_type", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "test_entity_id"))
private Set<RecordType> recordTypes = new HashSet<>();

@ElementCollection
@Column(name = "record_type_id", nullable = false)
@CollectionTable(name = "test_entity_record_type1", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "test_entity_id"))
private Set<RecordType> recordTypes1 = new HashSet<>();

@ElementCollection
@Column(name = "record_type_id", nullable = false)
@CollectionTable(name = "test_entity_record_type2", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "test_entity_id"))
private Set<RecordType> recordTypes2 = new HashSet<>();
}
```

I have 1000 records of entity in DB. When i try to get 1000 entityes i see in logs:

- 1000 select to entity table
- 1000 select to test_entity_record_type table by test_entity_id
- 1000 select to test_entity_record_type1 table by test_entity_id
- 1000 select to test_entity_record_type2 table by test_entity_id

As result time of answer is very long.

How can i reduce the response time?

Comment: i think you wan use the lazy mode on the ElementCollection annotation as : @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.LAZY) if you are looking for a lazy mode

Comment: @OmarAmaoun in response i need to see all fields.

Comment: ElementCollections are harder to optimize than entity association mappings, since they don't have their own lifecycle and ids. You can't even query them via JPQL. Are you sure you don't want to switch to entity collection mappings?

Comment: @Przemek how it help me?

Comment: Yes as @Przemek said, jpql requests will be executed once in the database, while with spring data, it will have as many requests as there are relationships between the data. but to stay in the spring data, look at the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use  @BatchSize annotation:

```
@BatchSize(size = 1000)
private Set<RecordType> recordTypes = new HashSet<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

I redid the same test case, is the following configuration giving me a shorter time than the first one (properties file):

```
spring.jpa.open-in-view=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.provider_disables_autocommit=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.use_query_cache=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.generate_statistics=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=1000
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size=1000
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_inserts=true
spring.datasource.maxActive=5
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_updates=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.query.fail_on_pagination_over_collection_fetch=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.query.in_clause_parameter_padding=true

spring.datasource.hikari.poolName=Hikari
spring.datasource.hikari.auto-commit=false
spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.cachePrepStmts=true
spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.prepStmtCacheSize=250
spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.prepStmtCacheSqlLimit=2048
spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.useServerPrepStmts=true
```

hope this would be helpful.